# Best way to refresh page

Tags: asp.net

Ok, I have a hyperlink on my page and that hyperlink is held within a user control.  When the user clicks that link, it's used to remove an item on the page, so:

```
<a href='<%#string.Format("{0}?removeItem=true&ItemID={1}", CurrentPage, Container.DataItem.Id )%>'>Remove this item</a>
```

On click of the link, the code-behind of my user control checks for the removeItem bool and if set to true, removes that item:

```
        removeSavedItem = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["removeItem"]);

        if(removeItem)
            RemoveItem();
```

And here's my RemoveItem() method:

```
    protected void RemovItem()
    {
        int itemID = Util.ParamVal("savedItemID", 0);

        if (itemID > 0)
            service.RemoveItem(itemID);
    }
```

But I need my page to refresh because it's removing it but my repeater is not showing the list with the item removed.  What's the best way to approach this? Just do a rebind of the repeater or is there a cleaner way?  Maybe that's just the standard way?  Rebind after I remove it in this method?

Comment: actually yea, I'll have to redirect because I was doing this removal in Page_Load.  So the page doesn't refresh with the updated binding after removal.

Comment: If I was using like a linkButton, call a method on its event, then the page does refresh.  So using a standard hyperlink, and grabbing a querystring and performing the action does not do the same thing, you have to redirect after handling it.

Comment: I am confused how do you know which item is removed from the Repeater control. Since, I don't see you passing any ID or index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to redirect back to the same page.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to ajaxify the removal of the items, Unless you are changing a whole lot of things in the page.

As an answer to your question, you can do `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());`
Incase you want to do it from JavaScript for any reason then use `window.location.reload();`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not save removed items in your session so that refresh will not pick up them?

Answer (score 0):

this is with pah and query

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```